# UITabbar Images and title are not center aligned in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uiedgeinsets

I am working on application which uses Tabbarcontroller (There are two tabs )
Everything works fine on iphone but on ipad both the tabs comes in center of the screen

I want to show the title and images in center of each tab (considering the tab width is half of the screen)

While searching for these I came across UIEdgeInsetsMake

[Adjust iOS TabBar item title to the centre of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811337/adjust-ios-tabbar-item-title-to-the-centre-of-it) but no help with this.

I dont understand where to put this code. I tried to put it in FirstViewController and then in app delegate (one by one ) but nothing works for me

Here is my appDelegete Code :

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
//navController1.title = @"First Tab";
navController1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];

SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];
navController2.title = @"Second Tab";
navController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navController1,navController2, nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 tabBarController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 50);

tabBarController.viewControllers = array;

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629135/ios-development-why-dont-my-tabbar-buttons-autoresize-on-the-ipad) answer I would suggest you to do like this

1 Get the screen width and divide it by the number of tab bar items you have

2 Once divided assgin the mean value via `setItemWidth` to the `UITabBar`

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
int count  = [array count];
float width  = screenSize.size.width/count;
[[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:width];
```

Comment: Note that this will set the width of all tab bars in the app - usually you'd have just one, but you may still want to constrain the setting to each tab bar individually (tabBarController.tabBar.itemWidth = width).

Answer (score 5):

You should put this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews of your UITabBarController

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioningFill;
```

**Swift 4, 5**

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill
```

Comment: Awesome..simple and easy…:)

Comment: With the latest swift version, the logic is below.                  
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill

Comment: .fill didn't help for me, anyone else?